# How do I add an unmoving View at the top of my app?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an app that contains a view at the top containing an image and some text and a listview below it that you can scroll up or down. What would be the best way to create this layout?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkywv.png

Comment: put inside scroll view which parts you want to scroll

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? This is not so hard to find out just reading [Android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html). There is as always more than one way to do it including some controversy. Thus, not a good question for StackOverflow, see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldnt the easiest solutuion just be this.   Kind of copy and pasted from my code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listviewschedule"
        style="@style/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="-21dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:showDividers="none"/>    
</LinearLayout>
```